# Platformer game background smooth scrolling y-axis

Tags: scroll, libgdx, smooth-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm creating simple 2D platformer and I want that my background image update with my player1 y coordinate.
Here's my `Background` class

```
public class Background{

    private Sprite sprite, sprite2;
    public static int x = 50, y = 0;

    public Background(){
        sprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.back);
        sprite2 = new Sprite(TextureManager.back);
        isSprite = true;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }

    public void setPosition2(float x, float y) {
        sprite2.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    public void draw2(SpriteBatch batch) {
        sprite2.draw(batch);
    }

    public float getWidth(){
        return sprite.getWidth();
    }
}
```

and here's my method updateCamera

```
public void updateCamera(){
    float lerp = 0.2f;
    System.out.println("SCREEN " + screenY);
    camera.position.x += (player1.getHitBox().x - camera.position.x) * lerp;
    if(screenY < player1.getHitBox().getY()){
        camera.position.y += player1.getHitBox().y * lerp;
    }else{
        camera.position.y = (screenY - 250);
    }
    if(screenY < player1.getHitBox().getY() && player1.getHitBox().getY() > (screenY - Gdx.graphics.getHeight())){
        screenY += Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        Background.y = (int) screenY/2; // updating background y-axis!
    }else if(player1.getHitBox().getY() < (screenY - Gdx.graphics.getHeight())){
        screenY -= Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        Background.y = (int) screenY - Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); // updating background y-axis!
    }
    camera.update();
}
```

And everything works but my scrolling is not smooth. When my character position `player1.getHitBox().getY() > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` my background update quite slowly. Here's how it looks [visualy](http://giphy.com/gifs/3oEdvazikmnfqso2oE). Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You don't even use deltaTime in your code.

Comment: And why I need to use deltaTime? I just track my player position

Comment: Because if you use lerp, then you need deltaTime.